# minecraft model rotate on direction placed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am sure it has been somewhere already answered, I just couldn't find any good answers. I am trying to make a model that rotates based on which direction you place it. For example stairs, if you put it on south it is facing south etc.

Is it possible to make a model with this behavior on block like stone or must it me block with these behaviors already set like stairs?

As you can see on the image below, the stairs can be placed, and the model will change direction based of how you place them. I am asking if this is possible to make with non-orienting block like stone, dirt etc.

[image]

Comment: Unclear. Please explain in more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### That's not possible

Blocks where the rotation matters, such as stairs, chests, dispensers, etc. store their rotation via data values, and use this data value to determine their facing when loaded. For blocks with an orientation, the act of placing the block into the world actually changes the data of the block you just placed, e.g. `minecraft:chest:0` turns into a `minecraft:chest:2`.

However, **data values are nothing but 4 bytes of data** (i.e. a number from 0 to 15). Each block determines what to do with this data itself. Wool and stained glass use it to determine the color, for example, and the data value of the placed block is identical to that you are holding.